# How to check if each JSP is running in the right frame

Tags: javascript, jsp, frameset

My application runs in a Frame which is divided into 2 sections. Left navigation Menu
and the right section where all the JSP's are executed. By using following frame buster code
I make sure that my frames are not running inside another fraudulent frame.

```
   if(top != self) top.location.replace(self.location);
```

Now all the JSP pages that execute inside my frames needs to be checked if they are running inside the appropriate frame.

My frames structure look like following.

```
    <frameset framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="no" rows="105px,*">
    <frame name="header" id="header"  scrolling="no" noresize marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/common/nav_header.jsp">
    <frame name="content" id="content" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/common/glb_loading.html">
    </frameset>
```

How do I check that?

Comment: Instead of using frames, why not do jsp includes in sections of a table, or just use ajax?  Frames are a bad idea.

Comment: My project is already using frames. So I have to stick to that. Please help